# Prometheus query for sum of alerts sent out each hour

Tags: prometheus, promql

Hi I need to find the sum alerts sent out for past 24 hrs on an hourly count.
Can Prometheus query gives this information directly in the console. I can use
`sum(alerts)` and see the graph by selecting the timeframe.

But I need the amount of alerts sent out each hour in console so that I can copy that data to excel.

The `sum_over_time` query gives total data count for past 1d in console:

```
sum_over_time(alerts[1d])
```

Again there is no option to aggregate the total based on each hour.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `sum(increase(prometheus_notifications_sent_total[24h]))`.

It shows the increase of the `prometheus_notifications_sent_total` metric over the last 24h.

You might also want to deduct the number of dropped notifications from it `sum(increase(prometheus_notifications_dropped_total[24h]))`.